# Why Apache can run a command and root cannot?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, root, su, service-accounts

I have a server-side script executed by Apache running as `www-data`. The script runs fine on the server when called remotely (`http://example.com/script.sh`).

I am trying to run the same script on the same server as `root`, impersonificating `www-data`. It does not, even `su www-data -c 'id'` or `runuser -l www-data -c 'id'` fails with

```
This account is currently not available.
2016 Nov  4 09:45:54 eu1 Attempted login by root on /dev/pts/0
```

This account is indeed locked from interactive login (which is normal):

```
# grep www-data /etc/shadow
www-data:*:15246:0:99999:7:::
# grep www-data /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

**Since Apache manages to run something as `www-data` then `root` ought to be able to do the same. How to do that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
su -s /bin/bash www-data -c
```

Since www-data has no shell, you have to specify one with the `-s`option.